# False lacheck Unmatched "{" Error

Tags: lacheck

In the simple LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcommand{\defaultleftmargin}{0.25in}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I get the following errors with lacheck:

```
"hw01.tex", line 5: <- unmatched "end of file hw01.tex"
"hw01.tex", line 2: -> unmatched "{"
```

This is reported by Vim's syntastic running `lacheck` ver. `$Id: lacheck.lex,v 1.26 1998/03/07 07:46:45 abraham Exp $` on MacOS High Seirra.  The issue only seems to arise when `\newcommand` is followed by `{\def*}` (where `*` is zero or more other characters).  Removal of the curly brackets around `\def*` or any term other than `def` causes the issue to go away.

I found an [old bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=515897;msg=2) regarding a similar issue.  I did not see any talk of a fix.  Is this a bug or is there something I am missing?

**Edit**: The issue appears to not be limited to `newcommand`.  I get the same error for the line:

```
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{\defaultleftmargin}
```

Comment: I get the same. Maybe you should report it to the maintainers of `lacheck` as a bug

Comment: use `\newcommand\defaultleftmargin{0.25in}`  then there will be no error. Same for `\newlength`

Comment: @Herbert still a strange bug, as the syntax for both is fine.

Comment: @Herbert, I mentioned in the original question removing the curly brackets makes the warning go away. I assume the error is raised for a reason (unless it is a straight bug). If it is a bug, I expect it would have been reported earlier (other than one post on a Debian forum).  I will write to TeXlive and update when I hear more.

Comment: Updating mactex (via `brew`) did not fix the issue.  I reported it to the TexLive folks as a bug.

Comment: Is this bug solved now?

Comment: @Mensch No. It is not.